# Loop in control flow graph of a program versus checking whether program goes into infinite loop or not

Tags: decidability

Which of these is true or false.

1)If Control Flow graph(CFG) doesn't contain any loop, the program will never go into infinite loop.

2)If CFG contains loop, the program may or may not go into infinite loop.

Another question:-

3)Checking for infnite loop in a program is equivalent to checking for halting ability of turing machines.

Comment: 1) true
2) undecidable
3) true

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake. True, true, true. Deciding whether a program containing a loop will ever halt is undecidable.